# Excel VBA - search range and connected SQL ADODB recordsets for match write Resultset in column

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

I have an Excel (2010) table with two data sources:

1. Access 2010 DB
2. SQL Server 2008 R2

I have data in columns A:I from the Access DB. In column A I have the record's ID, this ID  corresponds to the ID column in the table from my SQL DB.

I am trying to search through IDs in column A and if it matches an ID in the SQL DB, I want to display data from the "coOverview" column from the SQL table in column J.

**In short, "If ID = coID, then write coOverView to column J"**

[image: Combined Dataset]
I have successfully been able to connect and retrieve the desired record-set and copy/fill down column J, so I know I am able to successfully connect and read the data in my SQL table. Now I need to copy the data in coOverview from my SQL table ONLY if the ID matches the ID in column A.

```
Sub RetrieveOverview()

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim query As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=**"

    cn.Open ConnectionString
    cn.CommandTimeout = 900


    query = "SELECT coOverview FROM SQLTable"

    rs.Open StrQuery, cn

    Sheets(1).Range("J2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End Sub
```

I don't know if I should be the conditions in the SQL statement or in a loop.

Comment: To be clear, you pull in both datasets and store them in cells in Excel? If so, I would pull both ranges into arrays and write a simple comparison loop. Should be plenty fast if you have a reasonable amount of data.

Comment: Kyle, 
No, I am not storing both datasets in cells. I am storing one dataset in a range (A:I) and I want to use the IDs in column A and match it to the ID in the table in my SQL DB that I am connecting to in my SQL statement. After I find the matching ID, I want to copy the corresponding data that is in column "coOverview" in my SQL table and write it to column J in my Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having?  You say that you have successfully been able to connect and retrieve the desired record-set and copy/fill down column J.  What are you trying to do beyond that?

Comment: You need to change the sql query.

Comment: @sshel207, it seems like you do house both queries in cells in the workbook. The line of code `Sheets(1).Range("J2").CopyFromRecordset rs` copies your record set to column J. See my answer below for a non-array looping solution. Otherwise, I recommend putting your query results (after adding the ID to the query) in a different location, and building an array looper to combine data sets.

Comment: @Kyle, I don't have both datasets on my spreadsheet. What I was trying to illustrate with the line of code: `Sheets(1).Range("J2").CopyFromRecordset rs` is that I was successfully able to make the connection to the SQL DB and that I was also successfully able to read/retrieve the correct resultset. What I want to do is, if the ID in column A of my Excel table matches the coID primary key in my SQL DB, to write the corresponding coOverview in Column J on my Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

This goes through Column A and adds unique values to a variable `str`. Once complete, `str` will look like `(138,353,....)`. You can then insert than into a `WHERE` clause in your SQL statement to only bring back results where the IDs match. Note that if you IDs are strings in the SQL DB, you will need to wrap them in single quotes while building the string. If the IDs are already unique in Column A, you can cutout the `If instr(1,str,c.Value) <> 0 Then` part. Also, if the IDs in Column A are unique, you can sort those, and bring the query back sorted, and put the recordset in Column J and everything should line up.

```
Sub RetrieveOverview()

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String, Ids as String
Dim query As String
Dim rng as Range, c as Range
Dim lrow as long

With Thisworkbook.Sheets("your sheet name")
   lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set rng = Thisworkbook.Sheets("your sheet name").Range("A1:A" & lrow)

For Each c in rng
   If instr(1,str,c.Value) <> 0 Then
      If str <> "" Then
         str = str & "," &  c.Value
      Else
         str = "(" & c.Value
      End If
   End If
Next c

str = str & ")"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=**"

cn.Open ConnectionString
cn.CommandTimeout = 900


query = "SELECT ID, coOverview FROM SQLTable WHERE ID in " & str

rs.Open StrQuery, cn

Sheets(1).Range("J2").CopyFromRecordset rs
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The sql statement should be something like this, where you would change  `tblSQLServer` and `tblAccess` to the actual names of your tables.

```
sSQL = "SELECT tblSQLServer.coOverView, " & _
            "FROM (tblSQLServer " & _
            "INNER JOIN tblAccess " & _
            "ON tblSQLServer.CoID = tblAccess.ID)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider an SQL Server distributed query using its [`OPENDATASOURCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/opendatasource-transact-sql) method to join the Access database table with SQL Server table by matching *ID* field. Pass this query in ADO recordset call:

```sql
SELECT mssql.[ID], acc.[Category], acc.[Name], acc.[Days], acc.[Costs], mssql.[coOverview]
FROM
   OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source=C:\Path\To\Access\Database.accdb')...myAccTable acc    
INNER JOIN
   mySQLTable mssql
ON acc.ID = mssql.ID
```